# Why is my CSS overriden?

Tags: html, css

This should be really basic and I thought I knew this by now. But obviously I'm missing something.

On line 4859 I have the following css:

```
.ui-panel-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-height: inherit;
  border: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

and on line 5643 I have the following css:

```
.ui-panel-wrapper {
  min-height: auto !important;
}
```

But the output is this:

[image]

Why isn't my last statement overriding the first statement?

Comment: Try using `0` instead of `auto`? I dunno if `auto` is a valid value for this property

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The warning symbol next to the rule indicates that it is being ignored because it is invalid, not because it's being overridden.  Hover over it to see the specific message.

As many others have pointed out, the value you needed was `0`, not `auto`.

Comment: You're right, but it's strange that MDN says `auto` is a [valid value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height).

Comment: @Jivings According to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/min-height) it is not.

Answer (score 3):

Use `min-height:0;` instead of `min-height:auto;`

`auto` is an invalid value.

Answer (score 3):

[MDN shows that it's a valid value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height), because it is supported in Firefox, but it will be ignored anywhere else it's not supported. You are getting a warning in Chrome (which is why it's being ignored), but you won't get the same warning in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

"auto" is not an accepted value for the min-height property. It is for height but not for min-height. It's being overwritten because it's not valid.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp

Use 0 or initial instead.

Comment: Oddly enough, Firebug thinks it is.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, here is the official [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-min-height)

> ***'min-height'***
>
> Value:    `<length>` | `<percentage>` | `inherit`
>
> Initial:      0

Quite ironic to see that W3Schools got it right over MDN for that one.

Comment: MDN is correct because Firefox allow this, but everywhere else is ignored.